# Using the python win32 inside a docker container to access host screen?

Tags: python, windows, docker, win32com

Is it possible to use the python win32 api using the following code **inside** a docker container, accessing the host to get a screen grab.

I'm thinking maybe install docker for windows, install the image, and run the python code inside, accessing host for screengrab.

I know you can bind ports, is there someway to bind access to host's GUI?

```
 # code from https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/grabscreen.py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api

def grab_screen(region=None):

    hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

    if region:
            left,top,x2,y2 = region
            width = x2 - left + 1
            height = y2 - top + 1
    else:
        width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
        height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
        left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
        top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)

    ...more code (see link)

    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
```